# Laravel. Can't insert data with spaces to database. Syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel and Eloquent. I am looking for a way to insert data to database, but it seems when value has empty spaces i receive a syntax error.

How could i fix that or what i should use instead of Data::raw();

My code for inserting data:

```
            $data = new Data;

            $data->name = Data::raw($name);
            $data->time = Data::raw($time);

            $data->save();
```

Error i am receiving:

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '09:15:00)' at line 1 (SQL: insert into `data` (`name`, `time`) values (Name, 2020-08-05 09:15:00))

For example if i only pass date 2020-08-05 there are no error.

Comment: why $data->name = Data::raw($name); not just $data->name =$name;

Comment: can you show me your migration file for Data model?

Comment: Thank you, really helped me. I am new to php and laravel. Found that in tutorial, when example from documentation didn't worked, now i know, i didn't use that right in the first place,